# I am getting OOM while running PRE TRAINED Bert Model with new dataset with 20k

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I have pre trained model with Accuracy of 96 with 2 epochs and I am trying to use that model on new dataset of 20k tweets for sentiment analysis. while doing that I am getting below error.

I haven't faced any issues while training model with same size of data but not sure why I am getting while using that model.

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1079190,768] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:ResourceGather]
```

Code:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertForSequenceClassification
from transformers import InputExample,InputFeatures

model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

model.summary()

Model: "tf_bert_for_sequence_classification"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bert (TFBertMainLayer)       multiple                  109482240 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_37 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
=================================================================
Total params: 109,483,778
Trainable params: 109,483,778
Non-trainable params: 0

train = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory('aclImdb/train',batch_size=30000,validation_split=0.2,
                                                           subset='training',seed=123)
test = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory('aclImdb/train',batch_size=30000,validation_split=0.2,
                                                          subset='validation',seed=123)

Found 25000 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 20000 files for training.
Found 25000 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 5000 files for validation.


for data in train.take(1):
  train_feat = data[0].numpy()
  train_lab = data[1].numpy()

train = pd.DataFrame([train_feat,train_lab]).T
train.columns = ['DATA_COLUMN','LABEL_COLUMN']
train['DATA_COLUMN'] = train['DATA_COLUMN'].str.decode('utf-8')

for data in test.take(1):
  test_feat = data[0].numpy()
  test_lab = data[1].numpy()

test = pd.DataFrame([test_feat,test_lab]).T
test.columns = ['DATA_COLUMN','LABEL_COLUMN']
test['DATA_COLUMN'] = test['DATA_COLUMN'].str.decode('utf-8')
test.head()

def convert_data_to_examples(train, test, DATA_COLUMN, LABEL_COLUMN): 
  train_InputExamples = train.apply(lambda x: InputExample(guid=None, # Globally unique ID for bookkeeping, unused in this case
                                                          text_a = x[DATA_COLUMN], 
                                                          text_b = None,
                                                          label = x[LABEL_COLUMN]), axis = 1)

  validation_InputExamples = test.apply(lambda x: InputExample(guid=None, # Globally unique ID for bookkeeping, unused in this case
                                                          text_a = x[DATA_COLUMN], 
                                                          text_b = None,
                                                          label = x[LABEL_COLUMN]), axis = 1)
  
  return train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples

  train_InputExamples, validation_InputExamples = convert_data_to_examples(train, 
                                                                           test, 
                                                                           'DATA_COLUMN', 
                                                                           'LABEL_COLUMN')
  
def convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(examples, tokenizer, max_length=128):
    features = [] # -> will hold InputFeatures to be converted later

    for e in examples:
        # Documentation is really strong for this method, so please take a look at it
        input_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
            e.text_a,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=max_length, # truncates if len(s) > max_length
            return_token_type_ids=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
            pad_to_max_length=True, # pads to the right by default # CHECK THIS for pad_to_max_length
            truncation=True
        )

        input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask = (input_dict["input_ids"],
            input_dict["token_type_ids"], input_dict['attention_mask'])

        features.append(
            InputFeatures(
                input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, label=e.label
            )
        )

    def gen():
        for f in features:
            yield (
                {
                    "input_ids": f.input_ids,
                    "attention_mask": f.attention_mask,
                    "token_type_ids": f.token_type_ids,
                },
                f.label,
            )

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        gen,
        ({"input_ids": tf.int32, "attention_mask": tf.int32, "token_type_ids": tf.int32}, tf.int64),
        (
            {
                "input_ids": tf.TensorShape([None]),
                "attention_mask": tf.TensorShape([None]),
                "token_type_ids": tf.TensorShape([None]),
            },
            tf.TensorShape([]),
        ),
    )


DATA_COLUMN = 'DATA_COLUMN'
LABEL_COLUMN = 'LABEL_COLUMN'


# We can call the functions we created above with the following lines:

train_InputExamples,validation_InputExamples = convert_data_to_examples(train,test,DATA_COLUMN,LABEL_COLUMN)

train_data = convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(list(train_InputExamples),tokenizer)
train_data = train_data.shuffle(100).batch(32).repeat(2)

validation_data = convert_examples_to_tf_dataset(list(validation_InputExamples),tokenizer)
validation_data = validation_data.shuffle(100).batch(32)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')])

model.fit(train_data, epochs=2, validation_data=validation_data)

#this is my new data with 20k rows on which I want to run pretrained model:

tweets_list = statement_df['sentiment'].tolist()

#this part of the code is serving that purpose

tf_batch = tokenizer(tweets_list, max_length=128, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='tf')
#print(tf_batch)
tf_outputs = model(tf_batch) # this line is thrown OOM issues
tf_predictions = tf.nn.softmax(tf_outputs[0], axis=-1)
labels = ['Negative','Positive']
label = tf.argmax(tf_predictions, axis=1)
label = label.numpy()
for i in range(len(tweets_list)):
  print(tweets_list[i], ": \n", labels[label[i]])
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in gather_v2(params, indices, validate_indices, axis, batch_dims, name)
   4830       name=name,
   4831       axis=axis,
-> 4832       batch_dims=batch_dims)
   4833 
   4834 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in gather(***failed resolving arguments***)
   4811     # TODO(apassos) find a less bad way of detecting resource variables
   4812     # without introducing a circular dependency.
-> 4813     return params.sparse_read(indices, name=name)
   4814   except AttributeError:
   4815     return gen_array_ops.gather_v2(params, indices, axis, name=name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in sparse_read(self, indices, name)
    701       variable_accessed(self)
    702       value = gen_resource_variable_ops.resource_gather(
--> 703           self._handle, indices, dtype=self._dtype, name=name)
    704 
    705       if self._dtype == dtypes.variant:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_resource_variable_ops.py in resource_gather(resource, indices, dtype, batch_dims, validate_indices, name)
    547       return _result
    548     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
--> 549       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
    550     except _core._FallbackException:
    551       pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6860   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6861   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6862   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6863   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6864 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1079190,768] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:ResourceGather]
```

Comment: You are trying to feed a huge sequence of 1 mln elements. Maximum sequence length is 512